# tkinter scrollbar with grid, it doesn't get linked

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I'm studying GUI, so please understand my poor codes below.

I was trying to make a program which gets game-character's information. So if you press the 'search' button, the list would be shown below. But... it only shows about 11 names due to the window size. So i wanted to put a scrollbar for that area, but I just don't know how to link the scroll bar to control the area. I meant, the scroll bar itself has created, and it does scroll itself, but it doesn't scroll the window I wanted. I must have linked it wrong but... not sure.

Below is the minimized example code, but it's still quite long and crude. Sorry for that again.
If anyone can enlighten me, it would be really great help for this and my future works as well.

```
import tkinter as tk

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
import time

global var_dict, input_id, output
var_dict = {}

def enter_call_back(event=None):
    output.grid(column = 0, row = 2, columnspan = 5 , sticky='w')
    output.insert(tk.END,"Text_Something")
    output.update()
    search_chr()

def open_browse(url_list):
    for url in url_list:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        webbrowser.open(url)

def search_inven(ch_id):
    
    if ch_id == "ch1" or ch_id == "ch13" or ch_id == "ch15" :
        num = 5
        url_list = ["something.url","something2.url"]
        self_count = 1
    else:
        num = 0
        url_list = []
        self_count = 0
        
    masterset = []
    masterset.append(num)
    masterset.append(url_list)
    masterset.append(self_count)
        
       
    return masterset

def search_chr():
    global var_dict, output
    
    for things in var_dict.keys():
        var_dict[things].destroy()
        
    chr_list = ["ch1","ch2","ch3","ch4","ch5","ch6","ch7","ch8","ch9","ch9","ch10","ch11","ch12","ch13","ch14","ch15"]
    
    output.insert(tk.END," Done! \n\n")
    
    var_dict = {}
    num = -1
    for ch in chr_list:
        num += 1
        var_dict["output%s" %num] = tk.Entry(frame_buttons, width = 125)
        
        result = search_inven(ch)

        if result[0] == 0:
            var_dict["output"+str(num)].insert(0, "Clean "+ch+"\n")
            var_dict["output"+str(num)].grid(column = 0, row = num, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
        else:
            
            url_list = result[1]
            var_dict["o-button%s" %num] = tk.Button(frame_buttons, command=lambda url_list = url_list : open_browse(url_list))
            var_dict["o-button"+str(num)].grid(column = 1, row = num, sticky='e')
            var_dict["o-button"+str(num)].config(text="URL")
            
            var_dict["output"+str(num)].insert(0, "Not Clean "+str(result[0])+" Self : "+str(result[2])+" Ch_id : "+ch+")\n")
            var_dict["output"+str(num)].grid(column = 0, row = num, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
            
    vsb = tk.Scrollbar(frame_canvas, orient="vertical")
    vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    vsb.config(command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    
    frame_canvas.config(height = 300)
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("760x710")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.title("Minimum v.1.2")
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame_main = tk.Frame(root, bg="gray")
frame_main.grid(sticky='news')

intro = tk.Text(frame_main, height = 17, bg="#E3D5F3")
intro.option_add("*Font", "명조 10")
intro.insert(tk.CURRENT,"Text_something")
intro.config(state='disabled')
intro.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(5, 0), columnspan = 5, sticky='nw')

input_id = tk.Entry(frame_main, width = 35)
input_id.option_add("*Font","명조 10")
input_id.insert(0,"Ch_name")
input_id.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(5, 0), sticky='w')

search_btn = tk.Button(frame_main)
search_btn.config(text="Search")
search_btn.option_add("*Font","명조 10")
search_btn.config(width=5,height=1)
search_btn.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady=(5, 0), sticky='e')

output = tk.Text(frame_main, height = 10)
output.option_add("*Font","명조 10")
output.grid(row = 2, column = 0,pady=(5,0),sticky='nw')


frame_canvas = tk.Frame(frame_main, width = 565)
frame_canvas.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=(5, 0), columnspan = 3 ,sticky='nw')
frame_canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_canvas.grid_propagate(False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame_canvas, bg="gray", height=500,scrollregion=(0,0,500,1800))
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")


frame_buttons = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="gray")
frame_buttons.grid(row = 0, column = 0,sticky='e')


root.bind('<Return>',enter_call_back)
search_btn.config(command = enter_call_back)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First, you should not use `.grid()` to put `frame_buttons` into the canvas.  Use `canvas.create_window()` instead. Second, bind `<Configure>` event on `frame_buttons` and update canvas `scrollregion` inside the bind callback.

Comment: @acw1668 omg it worked!! Thanks a lot! Why don't you put the comment as an answer so that I can vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using `grid()` to put `frame_buttons` into the canvas will not affect the `scrollregion` of the canvas.  Use `canvas.create_window()` instead.

Second, it is better to bind `<Configure>` event on `frame_buttons` and update canvas' `scrollregion` inside the bind callback.  Then adding widgets to `frame_buttons` will automatically update the `scrollregion`.

Also note that you have created new `scrollbar` and put it at same position  whenever `search_chr()` is executed.  Better create the `scrollbar` only once outside the function.